# Idle 3.6 fails to install

Tags: python, pi-4, raspbian-buster, ide

I'm trying to install IDLE however I get this error message -

```
$ sudo apt-get install idle-python3.6

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 idle-python3.6 : Depends: python3.6-tk but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Where can I get python3.6-tk? I've tried `sudo apt-get install`-ing it, and `pip3 install`-ing it with no success.

Comment: Why are you trying to install the version for python 3.6? Buster has python 3.7 installed by default. I would expect that installing `idle3` will get you the correct one for your python version.

Comment: @Dirk doh! I'd forgotten that python 3.7 was a thing. It works, thanks!

Comment: @Dirk You should make an answer so the OP can accept it, otherwise the question will pop up again and again ...

Comment: @Jachdich You should accept the answer from *@Dirk*.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry I didn't see the answer. Accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian / Debian Buster uses Python 3.7 by default.

Installing `idle3` should install the correct module for your Python 3 version.